# How to extract the form data from a request in liberator?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, form-data, liberator

I have the following client-side request:

```
(let [form-data (doto
                       (js/FormData.)
                     (.append "filename" file))]
     (ajax-request
      {:uri "/some/uri"
       :method :post
       :body form-data
       :format (raw-request-format)
       :response-format (raw-response-format)})
     )
```

And on the server (with liberator):

```
(defresource some-resource [_]
  :allowed-methods [:get :post]
  :available-media-types ["application/json"]
  :exists? (fn [ctx]
             (prn "form-data " (-> ctx :request :body slurp)) ;prints
             (prn "form-data " (-> ctx :request :body slurp cheshire/decode)) ;doesn't print
             ))
```

At the server, I do get the print of the form-data like so:

```
"form-data " "------WebKitFormBoundaryI9CA2zKhFT0Stmx7\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"new-name\"\r\n\r\n{:uploaded-file #object[File [object File]], :name \"somename\", :another \"1234\"}\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryI9CA2zKhFT0Stmx7--\r\n"
```

But the next prn doesn't print anything where my goal is to extract the :uploaded-file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This might be an example-only thing, but be aware that a `:body`'s `InputStream` is "consumable".
We "can't" `slurp` it twice, as the first invocation moves the "marker" to the end of the stream.

Comment: Yes thanks. In test I've tried both prn's individually too with the same result.

Comment: That does not look like a JSON body at all? I'd assume, that this is a multipart form body